# @types/react@18 caused children prop not to work anymore

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am try to fix an issue with rect-redux provider not having the prop children anymore since @types/react@18. I have tried to set a version in the package.json, but that doesn't solve it. So to fix it, I want to manually add the prop children, I have the following example, but that still shows the error:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store/index';

type Props = {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}
const StoreWrapper: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export default StoreWrapper;
```

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you update `react-redux` types as well?

Comment: @mandy8055 it might be a possible duplicate, but the other question didn't solve the issue for me. As I tried those solutions as well.

Comment: @Konrad, wow and weird, I did try that before and didn't work at the time. Now it seems to work.

Comment: @udarts, so indeed it was type version mismatch right?

Comment: @mandy8055, weird, as I hadn't specified the types before (and it worked fine). Now once set to 7.1.28, it was fixed

Comment: @udarts cool it's sorted...good luck